# Error "Subscription was not found" when trying to create Azure Function App in VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm gettting rather weird error when attempting to create new Azure Function App with Azure Functions VS Code extension:

`Subscription MY_SUB_GUID_HERE was not found.`

No matter what I've tried: reloading VS Code, re-installing Azure Functions extension (incl. older versions), logging out from my MS account in browser, restarting PC, clearing TenantId in VS Code Azure Account extension, removing Azure Functions extension completely including its folder in *C:\Users\USER_NAME\.vscode\extensions*, signing out and back in via Azure Account extension, creating Azure Function application through the Azure portal incl. new resource group (I've found some old issue on GitHub which supposedly got fixed and one workaround was to create Azure func app through the portal first) - still the same error message, which occurs after selecting location, but actually in VS Code Log (Window) I can see that it fails immediately after 1st step (error code is **SubscriptionNotFound** + error message above) when you provide a unique name for the application.

At the same time, creating App Service, Resource Group, Static Web App all works like a charm through the corresponding extensions. Of course I see my subscription on Resources pane in VS Code and hence I'm saying that the error is a weird one.

OS: Windows 10 Pro x64 21H1, build 19043.1826
VS Code: 1.69.2
Azure Functions extension: 1.7.4
Azure subscription: free trial
Azure Functions version: ~4
.NET: 6.0

I cannot understand for love of god where the problem is - friend of mine tried it with his Visual Studio Enterprise subscription and it worked without any problem, so perhaps this is an account-related issue? Strange though that other things like App Service seem to work fine. I have "Owner" role for this subscription so it should not be due to the lack of rights or something similar.

Comment: I'm hitting this error as well.  I'm using a Microsoft account connected to my business, so I'm wondering whether this is causing it too? About to try on a completely different machine to check if it's an environment issue.

Comment: I was getting the same error with a Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription, and managed to fix by creating a function app, then actually creating and deploying a simple hello world function all through the portal. Then I restarted VS Code, signed out of Azure, then signed back in and now it works. Just creating an empty function app with no functions in it wasn't enough in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Have you updated the az-cli?

e.g. `az login` or `az logout`?
What does `az account show` shows you?

Comment: az-cli upgraded, ```az login``` (despite logging me in) as well as ```az account show``` display my Azure subscription , ```az logout``` log me out - i.e. nothing looks suspicious here...besides as I said above creating App Service or Resourse works just fine, only creating a Function App doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

- You will be facing this issue because the Azure subscription is absolutely completely empty and the environment could not able to pick up your subscription.
- Restart your environment after deploying a sample resource to your subscription.
- Now that the subscription is not empty, It will be able to identify your subscription id. Additionally, confirm that your Azure free trial membership has not expired.

Comment: I had an empty tenant with an empty subscription and had a similar error, while trying to create a storage account with the AZ CLI. I read this advice and tried it ... and it worked: I created a dummy resource group and inside it a dummy storage account with the Azure Portal Website. After that I executed my AZ CLI script and it succeeded. It may still be a user permission propagation issue that unfortunately coincided with my attempt, but I don't think, because I tried over 30 minutes long to log in, log out, log in, log out without success before